# Angular 7 mat-checkbox not being checked with reactive forms

Tags: angular

I am using Angular7 mat-checkbox with reactive forms. Below is the code.

```
shared: FormGroup;
 constructor(private router: Router, fb: FormBuilder,private filterServices:FilterServices) {
        this.shared = fb.group({
            "byAll": false,
            "byFriends": false,
            "byPeers": false,
            "byExperts": false,
            "bySpecificFriends": false,
            "byNone":false,
            "permissionType":"share",
            "emails": []
        });
}
```

On nginit function i am getting data from db as shown below

```
  ngOnInit(){
       this.filterServices.getFilters(12).subscribe((res)=>{
        console.log(res);
        this.setFormvalues(res);
       }) 
    }
setFormvalues(response:any){
     response.forEach(element => {

             this.sharedEmails = [];
             this.sharedEmails = element['emails'].split(',');
             this.shared.value['byAll'] = element["byAll"]
             this.shared.value['byExperts'] = element['byExperts']
             this.shared.value['byFriends'] = element['byFriends']
             this.shared.value['byNone'] = element['byNone']
             this.shared.value['byPeers'] = element['byPeers']
             this.shared.value['bySpecificFriends'] = element['bySpecificFriends']
             console.log(this.shared)
       })
}
```

I am able to set the data to the properties in shared object, but checkboxes in html is not getting checked. Suppose shared['byAll'] was initially false (checkbox initially unchecked),but after getting data fro service calls now its value is true. But in html its not getting reflected i mean checkbox is not getting checked. Am i going wrong somewhere??

below is the html code.

```
<form [formGroup]="shared">
                        <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="20px">
                            <mat-checkbox formControlName="byAll">All</mat-checkbox>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: You are looping over the response and overriding Form values again and again. Also, I don't think setting value to the form this way would work, call `setValue()` over the formgroup directly (as the control name and data keys are same) or `setValue()` to the form controls individually

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
this.shared.value['byAll'].setValue(element["byAll"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution!

We can use patchValue if we are updating only few values,else if we want to update all the values in a form group then use setValue.

patch value format

```
this.shared.patchValue({
"key":"value"
})
```